# How to implement roles in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

If I have a controller which has [authorize(role="admin")],
how do I create the admin role and add a user to the role?
Many people suggested I create a new class and many other changes but it's quite difficult to implement this and I'm wondering if there is a simpler way.

Here's what I have found.

Where should I put this?

```
        Roles.CreateRole("admin");
```

and where should i implement this

```
        Roles.AddUserToRole(User.Identity.Name,"admin");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use it in an ActionResult and it looks like this depending on implementation :

```
    public ActionResult Create(string RoleName)
    {
        Roles.CreateRole(RoleName);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And again for adding role:

```
 public ActionResult AddToAdmin(User user)
    {           
        Roles.AddUserToRole(user.UserName, "admin");                    
        return RedirectToAction("Index");             
    }
```

Comment: there's an exception happened when i'm creating a new role that says i have to enable the rolemanger can you help me please i'm really confused with identity